# android currency in textview

Tags: android, select, currency

I have very recently started to study Android and I'm doing a small project that I need for school, I found and adapted to my needs with the code below which fetch values ​​from Db and I view them in a Textview. It all works fine but these values ​​should be displayed in the format 'Currency' 00:00
I have read information on the net but have not been able to adapt the TextView with that format, can someone help me?

```
private class Dettaglio {


    double entrate;
    double uscite;
    double risparmio;

}
```

while (c.moveToNext()){

```
            Dettaglio d = new Dettaglio();

            d.entrate = c.getDouble(0);
            d.uscite = c.getDouble(1);
            d.risparmio = c.getDouble(2);

            dettagli.add(d);
        }
        c.close();
    }

    db.close();

    ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Dettaglio>(this, R.layout.dettaglio_row, R.id.tv_mese, dettagli){

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            Log.v("Bilancio", "Creo elemento in posizione "+position);

            String month = new DateFormatSymbols(Locale.getDefault()).getMonths()[position];
            TextView tvMonth = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_mese);
            tvMonth.setText(month);

            TextView tvEntrate, tvUscite, tvRisparmio;
            tvEntrate = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_ele_uscita);
            tvUscite = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_uscita);
            tvRisparmio = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_risparmio);


            Dettaglio d = dettagli.get(position);

            tvEntrate.setText(d.entrate+"");
            tvUscite.setText(d.uscite+"");
            tvRisparmio.setText(d.risparmio+"");
            return row;
        }
    };
    lista.setAdapter(adapter);

    //Calcolo il totale annuale
    double totaleE = (double) 0;        
    double totaleU = (double) 0;        
    double totalerisparmio = (double) 0;    


    double val = (double) 0;
    double val1 = (double) 0;



    for (Dettaglio d : dettagli){
        totaleE += d.entrate;
        totaleU += d.uscite;

    }

    TextView riepilogoE = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_riepilogo_entrate);
    TextView riepilogoU = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_riepilogo_uscite);
    TextView risp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_riepilogo_risparmio);


    riepilogoE.setText(""+totaleE);
    riepilogoU.setText(""+totaleU);

    val = Float.parseFloat(riepilogoE.getText().toString());
    val1 = Float.parseFloat(riepilogoU.getText().toString());


    totalerisparmio = val - val1;

    risp.setText(""+totalerisparmio);

}
```

Comment: What kind of data is stored into your field (column 0 of your cursor) ? An example of what shows your textview ?

Comment: decimal is entered and the database column is of type TEXT

Comment: What does your textview shows for now ?

Comment: the TextView is not set for any type of data. if I enter a value (1258654.40) I get 1.25872e +06, instead I would like € or $ 1.258.654.40

Comment: Sorry for the questions  but i was trying to understand what you really want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Try

etichetta1.setText(String.format("$%.2f", Float.valueOf(c.getString(0));

Comment: i have error : Caused by: java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier:  .2

Comment: Sorry, I missed a quotation mark.
I've edited my answer to fix that now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok

Use NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance() ;

```
Double value = Double.valueOf(c.getString(0)) ;
NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
String gainString = formatter.format(value );
etichetta1.setText(gainString);
```

Comment: this is how I have error in parseString, eclipse tells me to change toString

Comment: error in this line: Double value = Double.parseString(c.getString(0)) ;

Comment: ok and if I want to apply in different TextView Number format in the same activity, every time I have to repeat all the code? thank you very much

Comment: You can make a function for that or directly store the well formatted String in database whan String is entered. Don't forget to accept the answer if it does the job.

Comment: last thing. I enter number in the format GetView method. how do I? I entered my GetView method in the first post.
thanks